# Are inconsistent language tags bad for SEO

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, search-engines, language

Our website offers 3 languages in the following manner:
-**English**:  `www.example.org/en` with `<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">`
-**Spanish**:  `www.example.org/es` with `<html xml:lang="es" lang="es">`
-**French**:  `www.example.org/fr` with `<html xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">`

However when we check in `Google Analytics`, we can see that Google has generated much more [language tags](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/) (some in the form of a `language`, others in the form of `language+region`).

[image]

My understanding is that the `<html lang>` tag doesn't dictate how Google considers the content language, instead Google determines the language based on the actual analysis of the content, which I believe shows that our content is actually inconsistent.

**Q1: Is this negative to our SEO, and if so in what measure?**

When we click on the reported languages, all we see is a pretty useless view which only shows the selected language accounting for 100% of itself:

[image]

**Q2: Can we see which pages were identified as being of a certain language?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [user agent language headers](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032741), not content language tags.

Comment: Indeed, what a miss.